# Teardown called in the middle of a test Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot, minitest

I have been trying to create the following test : 
Edit a model (client side), check if the view is updated and if the model changed in database.

there is the code :

```
  test 'a' do
     user = User.joins(:organization_users).find_by organization_users: { role: OrganizationUser.roles.values_at(:ORGANIZER, :ADMINISTRATOR) } 

    sign_in_user user

    criterion = create(:criterion, scoring_id: @scoring.id, name: "Test criterion name", 
                        description: "Test description")
    step = create(:step, criterion_id: criterion.id)

    visit "scorings/" + (@scoring.id).to_s + "/criteria"

    find("#criteria > div > div > a > i").click()

    fill_in 'name', with: 'New name'
    fill_in 'description', with: 'New description'

    find('#criterion-modal > div:nth-child(2) > form > div:nth-child(4) > input').click()

    criterion = criterion.reload

    assert criterion.name == 'New name'

  end
```

`
Driver :

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new app , { phantomjs: Phantomjs.path }
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
```

Teardown :

```
teardown do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
end
```

As you can see at the end of the test i reload the criterion, but when i do that the teardown function is called. After that the Database is cleaned and i get the error "cant find criterion id:1". I'm only using minitest , factory girl and Capybara. So what i want to understand is why Teardown is called since its not the end of the test and how can i fix that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what you have setup for your teardown method, nor do you specify what driver you are using with Capybara.  However, since the test code and the teardown are run in the same thread there really is no way for the teardown to run before the test has ended.  What is possible (when using a JS capable driver, where clicks are processed asynchronously) is for the teardown to run before a click is processed/handled by the app code.  That would mean the  "cant find criterion id:1" would actually be coming from your controller code.  The reason for this is that you're not actually checking for anything on the page to change after clicking so the test just keeps on moving, finishes (failing the assertion), the teardown cleans and the controller action can't find the record.  Something like

```
assert_text 'Criterion updated' # if a message is displayed on successful update
```

or

```
assert_current_path("scorings/#{@scoring.id}") # whatever path it redirects to after updating
```

after the `click` and before your `reload`

On a side note - Using long selectors like '#criterion-modal > div:nth-child(2) > form > div:nth-child(4) > input' will lead to really brittle tests -- It would be much nicer to use simpler selectors or the capybara click_button type helpers if possible

Comment: Thank for your advise, i edited my post and added what you said was missing. I'm failing to understand something, The teardown is for sur called before the end of my test ends, i verified that with some debugging message. I'm checking something on my page now. The update request is an Ajax one soo after the submit i'm checking if the view has indeed been updated. But the same error keeps popping when i reload. What i really want to do here is just check if the view has been updated and if the criterion object has been updated in data base.

Comment: @TyLO  Where did you put the debugging messages that you think are verifying the order?  It's just not possible for the teardown to run before the test code completes (unless you're running parallel tests and have issues in that setup).   In your teardown you should call `Capybara.reset_sessions!` before calling `DatabaseCleaner.clean` and there should be no need to close the connection.  If that doesn't solve your issue please add the command thats checking something on the page to your test so it's complete, and add the location of the debugging messages and the actual output you get.